# how to create disk utilization cloudwatch alarm with boto3

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-cloudwatch

i want create disk utilization cloudwatch alarm with boto3 but i have problem to get the value of fstype, path and device . i create alarms with

```
 CW_client = boto3.client('cloudwatch', region_name='eu-west-1')
 response0 = CW_client.put_metric_alarm(AlarmName='disk utilization '+instancename, ComparisonOperator='GreaterThanThreshold', EvaluationPeriods=1, MetricName='disk_used_percent', Namespace='CWAgent', Period=300, Statistic='Average', Threshold=80.0, ActionsEnabled=True, AlarmActions=[topic], AlarmDescription='disk utilization for linux', Dimensions=[{'Name': 'device', 'Value': instance_id}, {'Name': 'device', 'Value': ?????}, {'Name': 'fstype', 'Value': ?????}, {'Name': 'path', 'Value': ?????}],Unit='Percent')
```

how i get fstype, path and device with boto3 ?

Comment: Are you currently sending such metrics to CloudWatch? Amazon EC2 does not send these metrics by default. You need to run some additional software (eg CloudWatch Agent) to publish such information to CloudWatch.

Comment: i install cloudwatch agent in EC2 and i created some alarms (CPU_Utilization, Status_Check ,...)with the code but in  disk utilization alarm i find difficult to get   the value of fstype, path and device

Comment: Are you able to view the metrics that are being received in CloudWatch? The first step in creating an Alarm is to look at the data being received so you can see the values for dimensions, etc. You can use [`aws cli list-metrics`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudwatch/list-metrics.html) to obtain details of metrics that have been received.